# Use Javascript to loop through an JSON object and return the indexes of the matching criteria

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have found this previous answer that semi-answers my question but I want to return an array of the indexes in which they appear - in this case ** 18A38** would return the location [1,3].

Entries are only an example - the final version would have potentially hundreds of entries.

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38'] 

const dataOject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  }
  , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
  , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
  ];

const result = checkArray.map(val=>dataOject.findIndex(el=>el.id===val) )


console.log( JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: btw, you have an array not a [JSON](https://json.org/), which is always a string.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start with the dataOject array first. have you though about doing a findIndex?
This way you may support your checkArray.

```
checkArray = ['18A38',"18A38"]

dataObject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
 , { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  }
 , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
 , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
 , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
];


const filteredData = checkArray.map(input => dataObject.findIndex(el => el.id === input));

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through and push the indices you need onto an array

```
const checkArray = ['18A38'] 

const dataOject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  }
  , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
  , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
  ];
let foundIndices = []
for (let i = 0; i < dataOject.length; i++) {
   if (dataOject[i].id === checkArray[0]) {
      foundIndicies.push(i)
   }
}

return foundIndices
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkArray` array is of length 1. Of course after using `map` you'd get only one value back.

I'd do it that way:

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38'] 

const dataOject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  }
  , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
  , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
  ];
  
  const result = dataOject.reduce((final, value, index) => {
    if (value.id === checkArray[0]) {
        return [...final, index];
    }

    return final;
  }, []);

  console.log(result);
```

---

If potentially `checkArray` is of more values, you also could do:

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38', '853K83'] 

const dataOject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  }
  , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
  , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
  ];
  
  const result = dataOject.reduce((final, value, index) => {
    if (checkArray.includes(value.id)) {
        return [...final, index];
    }

    return final;
  }, []);

  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38'] 

const dataObject = [
  { id:'853K83', isGo:false },
  { id:'18A38',  isGo:true  },
  { id:'97T223', isGo:true  },
  { id:'18A38',  isGo:false },
  { id:'182B92', isGo:true  },
];

const result = dataObject.reduce((acc, val, i) => { 
  if (checkArray.includes(val.id)) {
    acc.push(i)
  }
  return acc;
}, [])


console.log( JSON.stringify(result))
```